# Is there a word or short phrase that corresponds to "dunk" in English?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

It seems like "demergo" and "immergo" may have some close linguistic domains to the English word 'dunk' but I'm not sure. Is there a Latin word which would work equally well for dunking a donut and dunking a basketball?

Answer (score 6):

Si sermo est de mergendis, exempli causa, crusticulis in lactem:

→

… vel de mergendo toro oleo fervido cocto in cafeum, ut mos barbaricus est Americanorum:

→ ☕

… vocabulum [**tingere**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtingo), vel potius frater ejus, [**intingere**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dintingo) aptissimum mihi videtur. Sed id vocabulum non significat motum deorsum, neque motum in vasem, etc., sed res madefacere quovis humore. Qua de causa id non pertinere ad ludum pilae canistrique  arbitror.

Comment: Immo mos lepidissimus! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since a [Dunker](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dunker) (German *Tunker*) is originally a member of an Anabaptist Sect practising triple immersion, use *baptizo, baptizare,* Late ecclesiastical Latin, Greek loan word.

Comment: I think "Dunker" as an informal name for the sect comes from the common German word "dunken/tunken," i.e. the Baptism sense comes from the immersion word, not vice-versa.  βαπτίζω would be an excellent Greek translation of the term, but I think Latin *baptizo* introduces a religious sense that wouldn't be appropriate for "dunk"--though it would certainly be colorful!

Comment: Who doesn't like a cookie baptized in milk?